# POST Data from Arduino to Django Server on Pythonanywhere Return 404

Tags: python, django, arduino, http-post, pythonanywhere

I have been trying for a while now to use the HTTP POST method to send data to my Django server on pythonanywhere.com, but I keep getting a 404 error. I can't think of anything wrong with the URL (Even though there must be), but below is my code for both Arduino and Django:

**Arduino**:

```
#include "arduino4G.h"

// APN settings
///////////////////////////////////////
char apn[] = "phone";
char login[] = "";
char password[] = "";
///////////////////////////////////////

// SERVER settings
///////////////////////////////////////
char host[] = "marcoprouve.pythonanywhere.com";
unsigned int port = 80;
char resource[] = "/sensors4G/sensor_log/";
char data[] = "\"Name\": \"Marco\"";
///////////////////////////////////////

// variables
int error;


void setup()
{
  error = _4G.ON();
  if (error == 0)
    Serial.println(F("module ON..."));
  else
    Serial.println(F("module OFF"));

  Serial.println(F("Start program"));

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // 1. sets operator parameters
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  _4G.set_APN(apn, login, password);

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // 2. Show APN settings via USB port
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  _4G.show_APN();
}


void loop()
{
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // 1. Switch ON
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////  
  error = _4G.ON();

  Serial.println(F("Start program"));

  if (error == 0)
  {
    Serial.println(F("1. 4G module ready..."));

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 2. HTTP POST
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Serial.println(F("2. HTTP POST request..."));

    // send the request
    error = _4G.http( POST_METHOD, host, port, resource, data);

    // check the answer
    if (error == 0)
    {
      Serial.print(F("Done. HTTP code: "));
      Serial.println(_4G._httpCode);
      Serial.print("Server response: ");
      Serial.println((const char *)_4G._buffer);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print(F("Failed. Error code: "));
      Serial.println(error, DEC);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Problem with the communication with the 4G module
    Serial.println(F("4G module not started"));
    Serial.print(F("Error code: "));
    Serial.println(error, DEC);
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // 3. Powers off the 4G module
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Serial.println(F("3. Switch OFF 4G module"));
  _4G.OFF();

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // 4. Sleep
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Serial.println(F("4. Enter deep sleep..."));
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(F("5. Wake up!!\n\n"));
}
```

My Django Project (sensorLogger) **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import sensors4G.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', sensors4G.views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^sensors4G/', include('sensors4G.urls')),
]
```

My Django App (sensors4G) **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^sensor_log/', views.sensor_log, name='sensor_log'),
]
```

My Django App (sensors4G) **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect, csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Recent Request: POST')
    else: #GET
        print('Recent Request: GET')

        return HttpResponse("Hello, you're at the sensors4G index!")

@csrf_exempt
def sensor_log(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Recent Request: POST')
    else: #GET
        print('Recent Request: GET')

        return HttpResponse("Hello, you're at sensors4G sensor_log!")
```

I am not getting any print statement in my access logs on pythonanywhere and I keep getting a 404. If anyone has any suggestions or requires any more information I am very quick to respond and would love the help.

Thanks!

Comment: I accessed your page using the browser, and indeed, it seems to be fine. Perhaps you might be corrupting the resource[] somehow.... try to log it before sending a POST

Comment: And perhaps the problem is in the "arduino4G.h" module is it an Arduino library or your custom code?

Comment: If it helps, I know the POST method works in the Arduino Library (Not my own code) because I tested it on these paramters:

    char host[] = "test.libelium.com";
    unsigned int port = 80;
    char resource[] = "/test-get-post.php";
    char data[] = "varA=1&varB=2&varC=3&varD=4&varE=5";

The Above was able to reach the specified resource correctly. I have also noticed that the POST method examples that I have seen are directed toward php files, does this make a difference if I use my view handler in Django instead?

Comment: Im not a cloud expert... dont know much about the django side of your app. If you could sniff the sent data it would be possible to pinpoint where is the error. When I get a 404 it is usually because I messed up the url. But if you can use a sniffer in your server, you will be sure.

Comment: In fact, you can try to debug the resource by parts... try to use only "/" on the resource and see if you get a 404... then the first directory, and so on and so forth...

Comment: I used a sniffer to POST to my server and my server is picking it up okay. So it must be something with how the Arduino library sets up the resource. I will look into it and get back

Comment: django posts probably require the csrf token (or will get rejected). Is that being included in the header in your arduino POST? Also if your check your access logs on the pythonanywhere web server, do you see the POSTs?